# OAuth-Wrap Beginners Tutorial

Tags: php, javascript, oauth

Ok im looking for beginners OAuth-Wrap tutorials. I want to know where to begin. I will be using Javascript / PHP for my coding.  I want to play around with an API that uses OAuth-Wrap.

If can help me that would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out documentation of some frameworks that have implemented it. For example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

If you could call it a beginners tutorial at all... but this is as simple as it gets with OAuth.